# Link Private Repository to jCenter in bintray

Tags: github, bintray, jcenter

I published my project in the Bintray successfully, but when I tried to link it to the jCenter, I got this error message:

> Failed to send a message: The version control
>   "https://github-private-repository-url" returns 404.

My GitHub repository is private, so I want to know is it possible to link a private repo to the jCenter, and if yes how can I do that?

Comment: If a repo is private, only you and apps with permission can access the URL.

Comment: Are you using bintray's guidelines? see https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories.

Comment: Do you mean use private Bintray repositories or private Github repositories?

Comment: @Royg private github repository.

Comment: Just for clarification, you put your private repo in the `Version control` or in the `GitHub repo` option?

Comment: Anyone found solution for this ?

Comment: I found two solutions: 1) create a fake public repo and link it, or 2) upgrade to the pro edition . But I prefer the solution one.